# HTML5 web audio API Wavesurfer.js with filters

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I can use wavesurfer.js to play audio. Now I would like to add some filters (high & low pass) so that I can edit the audio. With wavesurfer player I can do fast forward, pause audio and then I want to apply filters on particular section. Basically I want control over audio play and apply filters on it.

What are the ways to achieve this?

Comment: Removed html5-canvas tag as this is not related to canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add filters via the method `setFilter`:

```
var lowpass = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createBiquadFilter();
wavesurfer.backend.setFilter(lowpass);
```

You can do this during playback, it will rewire itself automatically.

The filter node is connected to wavesurfer's gain node, which in turn is connected to the final destination (speakers).

See https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js#connecting-filters

*P.S. I've pushed this just now. Thanks for highlighting the issue!*

Comment: Thanks a lot @katspaugh. It worked!! But now I wanted to have multiple filters and I did like this   wavesurfer.backend.setFilter(higpassfilter);
wavesurfer.backend.setFilter(lowpassfilter);                       but it takes only last filter.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot connect WebAudio source to 2 different outputs, you need to chain them instead.

Comment: yeah, you are right.. I tried this highpassfilter.connect(lowpassfilter);
    wavesurfer.backend.setFilter(lowpassfilter);                           but it didn't work.

Comment: @pramodtech, it does work (I can tell by nearly becoming deaf after connecting notch to lowpass), however there's actually no point chaining biquad filters as they're opposite to each other's purpose.